# Gulp shows Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module

Tags: node.js, gulp

I installed node js on my system.After that i set the environmental varaiables.Then i tried to run  gulp after installing it but it shows Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module .
Can anyone help me to solve this

```
Node Version is v16.13.1

gulp Version is 
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

[image]

gulpfile,js
[image]

gulpfile link
https://codepen.io/ANANTHUC/pen/GRMovwG

Comment: Can you show your gulpfile.js?

Comment: @GOTO0 added the gulpfile link .Please check the codepen link

Comment: The package gulp-image that you require in your gulpfile seems to export an ES module, not a commonjs module. So have you tried, what is proposed by the error message. Use a dynamic import() instead of require()?

Comment: @ananthu The declaration on line 13 seems unused: `image = require("gulp-image")`. If you remove that line, you should no longer see this error (maybe a different error).

Comment: One more doubt if i need gulp-image task.How can i overcome this error can u pls help me with that also.I updated my codpen also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just degrade one version down to the Gulp-image and check.
I think it will work fine, because for me it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).